# How to get the path of a sub folder under root directory of the project in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Had to post this question again as my previous one was closed saying that my question wasn't focused. So here by I'm trying again.**

My Folder structure looks like this:

```
root_folder:
    - core
    - files
    - solution
        - sub_folder
             - test.py 
    - tests
```

I need to get the absolute path of sub folder `files` from the python file `test.py`.

Have tried various ways using `os.path.abs` and `os.path.dirname` but did not work for me.

Any help could be appreciated.

Tested code and output:

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'files'))
```

output: `/home/kulasangar/Documents/bst_work/root_folder/solution/files`

expected output:
`/home/kulasangar/Documents/bst_work/root_folder/files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.path` to access the root of your project from everywhere in your code.

```
import sys
print('My nested folder : ', os.getcwd())
print('File name : ', os.path.basename(__file__))
print('Root path:', sys.path[1])
```

Assuming the same folder structure you posted, my project folder is named `testing` . So, the output is

```
My nested folder :  /Users/hellbreak/Documents/Coding/Python Lab/testing/solutions/sub_folder
File name :  test.py
Root path: /Users/hellbreak/Documents/Coding/Python Lab/testing
```

Then, if you are interested in a particular path, you can

```
print('My nested folder : ', os.getcwd())
print('File name : ', os.path.basename(__file__))
print('Root path:', sys.path[1]+'/files')
```

The output:

```
My nested folder :  /Users/hellbreak/Documents/Coding/Python Lab/testing/solutions/sub_folder
File name :  test.py
Root path: /Users/hellbreak/Documents/Coding/Python Lab/testing/files
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of @hellbreak's answer, I figured out another way:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

current_dir = Path(__file__)
project_root_dir_path = [p for p in current_dir.parents if p.parts[-1] == 'root_folder'][0]
files_path = os.path.join(project_root_dir_path, 'files')
```